# Create Custom View

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view

I am trying to achieve the effect of creating a view with a custom shape(almost rectangular).

Here is what i tried to do:

```
public class CustomHeaderview extends View {

    public CustomHeaderview(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomHeaderview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomHeaderview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

    Path wallpath = new Path();
    wallpath.reset(); // only needed when reusing this path for a new build
    wallpath.moveTo(100, 100); // used for first point
    wallpath.lineTo(100, 200);
    wallpath.lineTo(200, 200);
    wallpath.lineTo(150, 100);
    wallpath.lineTo(100, 100);// there is a setLastPoint action but i found it not to work as expected

    canvas.drawPath(wallpath, paint);
    super.draw(canvas);
}

}
```

and the XML:

```
<CustomHeaderview
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="152dp" />
```

**EDIT**
Thanks Dmitry, it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You providing fancy coordinates for you rectangle:

```
x1: 100
y1: 100
x2: 100
y2: 120
```

So, you're getting rectangle with 0 width, thats why it is invisible.

Comment: I understand, can you give me an idea of how i could draw a trapezoidal shape using the canvas?

Comment: @AdrianOlar you can either draw it line-by-line, use `canvas.skew()` method, or `canvas.drawVertices()`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, i used the line-by-line method. I updated my answer